Как создать выборку таблиц? У меня есть 5 таблиц и я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог выбрать ту, которая ему нужна

Как вы видите, здесь есть DataGridView, кнопка и текстовое поле. 
Пользователь вводит данные в текстовое поле и 
выбирает таблицу с помощью оператора SELECT * FROM, а затем нажимает на кнопку.
Я хотел, чтобы можно было выбрать таблицу без необходимости писать код. 
Это помогло бы упростить процесс и сделать его более удобным для пользователей.
Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему.
Это мой код для кнопки
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText: textBox7.Text, nrthwndConnection);

     DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

     dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

     dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
 }


Сделать выпадающее меню, а при нажатии на кнопке выбирать ту БД, которая выбрана в списке?

Понимаете, нужно сделать так: вместо текстового поля должен быть список со всеми доступными базами данных. Пользователь выбирает нужную таблицу и нажимает кнопку.

В чем именно проблема? Нарисовать селект и положить в него список таблиц? Получить список доступных таблиц из БД? Сформировать пользовательский запрос на выборку данных при нажатии на кнопку?

я не знаю как это делается

Ну так надо научиться. Начните с начала, создайте селект(выпадающий список). Потом научитесь делать выборку из БД и результат помещать в этот селект. Сидеть и ждать готовый код - конечно можно, но тут вы его с такой постановкой вопроса врят ли получите.

Итого 1) получить список таблиц из БД 2) по полученному списку сформировать выпадающий список с названиями таблиц. 3) При нажатии главной кнопки считывать текущий выбор в выпадающем списке, исходя из текущего выбора, подставлять нужную подстроку в запрос. 4) профит
